# Eclipselink error 3002

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink, toplink

I am doing a simple migration from Toplink 10g to native Eclipselink v2.6.4 by following the instructions [here](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/toplink/TLADG/migrnativetoplink.htm#TLADG935) (particularly task 3 and 4). Everything compiles ok but when I try to run my app I get the error below.

I tried using the old mapping file (which is still compatible) as well as a new one generated from Eclipselink workbench by importing my old Toplink workbench project.

Note that I'm only doing a migration from Toplink to native Eclispelink. There is no JPA involved.

Any ideas on what`s wrong? It seems like it's trying to improperly using String instead of my actual class, but not sure.

Also, my app has never had a persistence.xml file. Do I need one now?

```
2017-02-20 14:55:52 ERROR - Presentation - Local Exception Stack: 
Exception [EclipseLink-3002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.4.v20160829-44060b6): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ConversionException
Exception Description: The object [ca.ncams.wisor.refdata.AccessTandem], of class [class java.lang.String], from mapping [org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.mappings.XMLDirectMapping[javaClass-->class/text()]] with descriptor [XMLDescriptor(org.eclipse.persistence.descriptors.ClassDescriptor --> [DatabaseTable(class-mapping-descriptor)])], could not be converted to [class java.lang.Class].
Internal Exception: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ca.ncams.wisor.refdata.AccessTandem
                at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ConversionException.couldNotBeConvertedToClass(ConversionException.java:98)
                at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.helper.ConversionManager.convertObjectToClass(ConversionManager.java:451)
                at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.helper.ConversionManager.convertObject(ConversionManager.java:146)
                at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.XMLConversionManager.convertObject(XMLConversionManager.java:197)
                at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatasourcePlatform.convertObject(DatasourcePlatform.java:179)
                at org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.mappings.XMLDirectMapping.getAttributeValue(XMLDirectMapping.java:301)
                at org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.mappings.XMLDirectMapping.valueFromRow(XMLDirectMapping.java:364)
                at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.DatabaseMapping.readFromRowIntoObject(DatabaseMapping.java:1539)
                at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.buildAttributesIntoObject(ObjectBuilder.java:462)
                at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.XMLObjectBuilder.buildAttributesIntoObject(XMLObjectBuilder.java:378)
                at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.XMLObjectBuilder.buildObject(XMLObjectBuilder.java:291)
                at org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.mappings.XMLCompositeCollectionMapping.buildCompositeObject(XMLCompositeCollectionMapping.java:380)
                at org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.mappings.XMLCompositeCollectionMapping.buildObjectFromNestedRow(XMLCompositeCollectionMapping.java:587)
                at org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.mappings.XMLCompositeCollectionMapping.valueFromRow(XMLCompositeCollectionMapping.java:511)
                at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.DatabaseMapping.readFromRowIntoObject(DatabaseMapping.java:1539)
                at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.buildAttributesIntoObject(ObjectBuilder.java:462)
                at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.XMLObjectBuilder.buildAttributesIntoObject(XMLObjectBuilder.java:378)
                at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.XMLObjectBuilder.buildObject(XMLObjectBuilder.java:291)
                at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.record.DOMUnmarshaller.xmlToObject(DOMUnmarshaller.java:469)
                at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.record.DOMUnmarshaller.unmarshal(DOMUnmarshaller.java:267)
                at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.record.DOMUnmarshaller.unmarshal(DOMUnmarshaller.java:246)
                at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.XMLUnmarshaller.unmarshal(XMLUnmarshaller.java:530)
                at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.factories.XMLProjectReader.readObjectPersistenceRuntimeFormat(XMLProjectReader.java:293)
                at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.factories.XMLProjectReader.read(XMLProjectReader.java:186)
                at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.factories.XMLProjectReader.read(XMLProjectReader.java:242)
                at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.factories.XMLProjectReader.read(XMLProjectReader.java:100)
                at ca.ncams.wisor.persistence.toplink.PersistenceManager.initializeTopLink(PersistenceManager.java:491)
                at ca.ncams.wisor.persistence.toplink.PersistenceManager.<init>(PersistenceManager.java:83)
                at ca.ncams.wisor.persistence.toplink.PersistenceManager.getInstance(PersistenceManager.java:96)
                at ca.ncams.wisor.persistence.toplink.AutoRollbackFilter.doFilter(AutoRollbackFilter.java:57)
                at ca.ncams.wisor.filter.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:124)
                at ca.ncams.wisor.presentation.filters.CatchAllFilter.doFilter(CatchAllFilter.java:60)
                at ca.ncams.wisor.filter.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:124)
                at ca.ncams.wisor.presentation.filters.NoCacheFilter.doFilter(NoCacheFilter.java:47)
                at ca.ncams.wisor.filter.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:124)
                at ca.ncams.wisor.filter.FilterJspBase.service(FilterJspBase.java:111)
                at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:286)
                at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:260)
                at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:137)
                at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:350)
                at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.onAddToMapException(ServletStubImpl.java:489)
                at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:376)
                at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:247)
                at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3679)
                at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.__run(WebAppServletContext.java:3649)
                at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java)
                at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:326)
                at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAsForUserCode(SecurityManager.java:197)
                at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSecurityProvider.runAsForUserCode(WlsSecurityProvider.java:203)
                at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:71)
                at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2433)
                at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2281)
                at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2259)
                at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.runInternal(ServletRequestImpl.java:1691)
                at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1651)
                at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:270)
                at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager._runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:348)
                at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager.runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:333)
                at weblogic.work.LivePartitionUtility.doRunWorkUnderContext(LivePartitionUtility.java:54)
                at weblogic.work.PartitionUtility.runWorkUnderContext(PartitionUtility.java:41)
                at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.runWorkUnderContext(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:640)
                at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:406)
                at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:346)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ca.ncams.wisor.refdata.AccessTandem
                at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
                at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
                at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
                at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
                at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
                at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
                at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.helper.ConversionManager.convertObjectToClass(ConversionManager.java:448)
                ... 61 more
```

Comment: The problem is occuring because your mapping files contain the "ca.ncams.wisor.refdata.AccessTandem" reference, and to load the project, it needs to convert it to a class but cannot, as you do not have the ca.ncams.wisor.refdata.AccessTandem file on the project's classpath.

Comment: Both the old and new mapping files contain the full package names. It works fine with the full names via Toplink but not EL. The files ca.ncams.wisor.* are the classes in my application, so they are definitely there. However I'm wondering if the order the classes are being loaded is different now. In the old system everything was in the WEB-INF/lib directory, but now EclipseLink is in the container. Would that make a difference? Is there a way to change the order?

Comment: Are you passing in the classloader that has your ca.ncams.wisor.* classes to the XMLProjectReader?  What ever loader is being used, it is unable to find the specified ca.ncams.wisor.refdata.AccessTandem class resulting in the exception.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I ended up doing:

1. Add Eclipselink 2.6.4 dependency to pom (compile instead of provided)
2. Add to weblogic.xml:

> ```
> <wls:container-descriptor>
>     <wls:prefer-application-packages>
>          <wls:package-name>org.eclipse.persistence</wls:package-name>
>     </wls:prefer-application-packages>
> </wls:container-descriptor>
> ```

Now Eclipselink finds my classes and boots up.

Note that my code was only passing in the mapping file and not a classloader to `XMLProjectReader.read();` so I guess was using the default classloader.

If anyone knows of how to pass in a classloader I'd still be curious to know (where do I get it from?).